# The program crashing with Firebase Android 4.4.4 and pre?

Tags: android

The application works fine on Android 5.0 and above, but depending on the versions 4.4.4 and per

My app build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.waelco.live2017"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile project(':InitActivity')
    compile project(':materialTabs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What problem is your opinion
Thank you

Edit: Android manifest

```
    <application
    android:name="com.waelco.live2017.GcmApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
```

Comment: Show your application class, and/or your Android manifest xml

Comment: @ianhanniballake What is the logcat

Comment: @EpicPandaForce

Comment: A really, really important skill if you want to continue to do development is to search for answers as most questions have already been answered. For example, a quick Google search brought up [this official article on logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Comment: This should be an edit to the question, but does your GcmApplication extend from MultiDexApplication?

Comment: How will extend to  MultiDexApplication

Comment: Please add application class